# Trying to display data from json with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display data from a JSON object.

```
<table ng-controller="statsCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
        <td>{{ stat.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ stat.id }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the following code

```
'use strict';

angular.module('stats', [])

    .controller('statsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.stats = [
            {
                name: 'player', 
                id: 1, 
                skills: [{
                    taming: 244,
                    mining: 25, 
                    woodcutting: 100
                }], 
            }
        ];
    }]);
```

But the view which is index.html isn't displaying anything.

```
{{ stat.name }} {{ stat.id }}
```

And I get the [following error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=mcmmo&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dmcmmo%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:21:334%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:20:483)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:21:218%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:35:146%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:34:428)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Lb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:38:146)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:17:339).

Not sure why. What am I doing wrong?

First time messing with AngularJS.

Comment: Your code seems right. I think the error came from another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/2EEDYMYq9tSYwXWSfm1c?p=preview

Seems to work fine, you might be missing ng-app or there might be another error which breaks your code along the way.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.stats = [
          {
              name: 'player', 
              id: 1, 
              skills: [{
                  taming: 244,
                  mining: 25, 
                  woodcutting: 100
              }], 
          }
      ];

}]);
```

With this HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
          <td>Name: {{ stat.name }}</td>
          <td>Id: {{ stat.id }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: After breaking it up and using app.controller it works. Thanks. Can you explain to me what could the difference be?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference, you can play with the plunker and see that both ways work. Might there be something in your on your machine that makes it different? The broken up way is just a formatting preference.